# How to show elements of custom data type in TFS custom build definition

Tags: tfs, custom-build

Is it possible to show the sub elements of a custom datatype in the TFS build definition file? For example in the 'Agent setting' the menu expands to its sub elements in the same way I want to show the elements of my own datatype.

```
<x:Members>
<x:Property Name="BuildNumberFormat" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
<x:Property Name="SolutionSpecificBuildOutputs" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
<x:Property Name="CleanWorkspace" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:CleanWorkspaceOption)" />
<x:Property Name="SourceAndSymbolServerSettings" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:SourceAndSymbolServerSettings)" />
**<x:Property Name="AgentSettings" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:AgentSettings)" />**
<x:Property Name="AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
<x:Property Name="CreateWorkItem" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
<x:Property Name="CreateLabel" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
<x:Property Name="GetVersion" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
<x:Property Name="PrivateDropLocation" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
<x:Property Name="Verbosity" Type="InArgument(mtbw:BuildVerbosity)" />
<x:Property Name="Metadata" Type="mtbw:ProcessParameterMetadataCollection" />
<x:Property Name="SupportedReasons" Type="mtbc:BuildReason" />
<x:Property Name="BuildProcessVersion" Type="x:String" />
**<x:Property Name="MapBuildConfig" Type="InArgument(ma:MyBuildConfig)" />**
```

In above code "AgentSettings" expands to its elements: Name filter, Tags filter so on..
But my custom type "MyBuildConfig does not expand to its elements...

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provided the code you talk about so people can see what you have tried so far

Comment: was that useful - Sorry It is hard to explain without attaching a screen shot I have no access to that as a new user :( ?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are looking for a [Custom Process Parameter editor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/01/18/tfs-2010-custom-process-parameters-part-3-custom-editors.aspx)?

Before going that route I suggest to reuse existing editors like [Bart suggests](http://bartwullems.blogspot.de/2012/07/tfs-build-using-built-in-editors.html) and adapting your custom type.